# Fontsize and MediaPlayer volume in WP7 app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, media-player, font-size

I have a few questions regarding designing the UI for `WP7`. These are valid since most of windows phone developers, I suppose, do not have actual device. So , questions are,

1. What should be the minimum font size for texts , so that it is readable on the device ?
2. I am playing background music using `XNA`'s  `MediaPlayer`. At what level volume should be set , I am looking for a thumb rule, so that it is audible enough but does not hides the game sounds.

Comment: Do you not have a WP7 device? I think it's more uncommon for mobile developers to not have at least one device for each platform they're targeting. Emulators only go so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out these things using the emulator. Use the zoom to change its size. It is really recommended to try the app on a device before you publish it.

Comment: size of emulator is bigger than that of the device , although resolution is same. So, I am not sure if emulator will reflect actual GUI experience. Also, on emulator, sound will be that of computer which might be very different , strength-wise, from actual device. I do not have any WP7 device, can you suggest how to go about it ?

Comment: You can reduce the size of the emulator to the size of a real device. But you won't be able to have the same experience as different devices have different screen sizes as well as amplifier and speaker. When you submit your app they will test it with 3 different kind of phones. I would recommend to get a device from somewhere. It's really needed to create high quality apps.